# Unable to select result from select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, select, jquery-select2

I have the following javascript/jQuery that pulls in data from via AJAX. That works fine however I can cannot seem to be able to select an option from the dropdown? Can anyone explain what I have done wrong..

This is something to do with the id..

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
  ajax: {
   url: "/admin/generator/teams",
   dataType: 'json',
   delay: 250,
   data: function (params) {
    return {
      q: params.term, // search term
      page: params.page
   };
},
processResults: function (data, params) {
  // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
  // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
  // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
  // scrolling can be used
  params.page = params.page || 1;

  return {
    results: data.items,
    pagination: {
      more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
    }
  };
},
 cache: true
},
 escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
 minimumInputLength: 1,
 id: function(data){ return data._id; },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should make sure `processResults` function returns an array of objects with `id` and `text` properties like this:

```
{ id: '1', text: 'Option 1' }
```

Then once the options are loaded, you can set the value by calling:

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").val('1').trigger('change');
```